# static function return new object alway set to null

Tags: c#, null

I would appreciate your help in debugging the below issue:

```
Toolbox

public static StdResult createLine(string extension, string site, string CSSLevel, string label)
        {
...
StandardResponse res = AXLAPIServiceSingleton.getInstance().addLine(req);
**// Return of a new custom object a the result**
return new StdResult(StdResVal.SUCCESS, res.@return);
}
```

---

```
MyClassA

// Execute the createLine function which return a new object
StdResult resActionAssociateLine = Toolbox.createLine(selectedUserExtension, selectedUserSite, valueCreateLineCSS, valueCreateLineFirstNameLastName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Result is always null: " + resActionAssociateLine.text);
```

---

```
namespace CUCMAdminPortal.CiscoAXL
{
    [Serializable]
    public class StdResult
    {
        public StdResVal res;
        public string text;

        public StdResult(StdResVal res, string text)
        {
            res = this.res;
            text = this.text;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the function always return a value which is not assigned to the receiving object "resActionAssociateLine". The object is always null. When from the function I return a string, the receiving object receives the string. It seems that the StdResult class is causing some issue.

Comment: `res.@return` where do you define `@return`? Is it a property name? Why would that ever be a good idea?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: The `@` prevents processing as a keyword and lets you use a normal identifier named `return`, in this case it looks like a property.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, I realized it is meant as a property the moment I posted it. Makes me shudder to realize people use it as a property name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignment is backwards in your constructor. You want to assign your parameter to your instance var.

```
public StdResult(StdResVal res, string text)
{
    this.res = res;
    this.text = text;
}
```